# Getting in my logs allot of requests with '+iurl+'&cb=

Tags: javascript, iphone, url

My server load is very high. And I think the reason as to do with this:

```
[29/Sep/2014:16:06:10 +0000] "GET http://www.example.com/expensive/went-broke/'+iurl+'&cb=745647 HTTP/1.1" 404 7741 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A405 [FBAN/FBIOS;FBAV/6.4;FBBV/290891;FBDV/iPhone3,1;FBMD/iPhone;FBSN/iPhone OS;FBSV/5.0.1;FBSS/2; FBCR/Bell;FBID/phone;FBLC/en_US;FBOP/1]"
```

It's like there was a javascript that was buggy. I know it's not coming from our side.

I am posting this here to see if anyone else has had the same issue. Also if anyone recognizes it.

Comment: Similar here. Getting badly formed URL - does not have `?` in it and at the end is '&cb=321321'

Comment: Same here, getting a lot of these, seems like an attack, but can't know for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CB = Cache Bustering, wrongfuly implemented.